# How to handle scrolling of fragment's layout inside SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-tabs

If i have to 2 tabs inside ViewPager.and each tab have it's own fragment associated with it.if the fragments of respective tabs have ScrollView as MainView .if i scrolldown the layout of first tab  and move to second tab and again swipe back to first it is in same scrolled state as i left it.

So How can i get the scroll automaticaly to the top when i click or swipe to tab.

i have tried Scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP); and Scrollview.scrollTo(0,0);

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    private int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created

    public ViewPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);
        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            Tab_1 tab1 = new Tab_1();
            return tab1;
        }
        else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            Tab_2 tab2 = new Tab_2();
            return tab2;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }}
```

SlidingTabLayout.java

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public interface TabColorizer {

        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    public interface TabIconProvider {
        int getPageIconResId(int position);
    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();

    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link //com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer} to be used.
     *
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */

    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    public void setTitleTextColor(int color) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (mTabStrip.getChildAt(i) != null && TextView.class.isInstance(mTabStrip.getChildAt(i))) {
                ((TextView) mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(color);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link //com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget.SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                private int mScrollState;
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
                    if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

                    View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
                    int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                            ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                            : 0;
                    scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

                    if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                        mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                                positionOffsetPixels);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                        scrollToTab(position, 0);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
                    }
                    if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                        mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    mScrollState = state;

                    if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                        mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                    }
                }
            });;
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            textView.setAllCaps(true);
        }

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip()
    {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();

        final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }

            tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
            tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }



    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager pager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
private CharSequence Titles[]={"Tab_1","Tab_2"};
private int Numboftabs =2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.AndroidApp.ActivityPackage.MainActivity">

     <com.AndroidApp.SlidingTab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tabColor"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

tab_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/srlview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_empnum"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter Employee Number"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_empname"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_empdob"
                android:inputType="date"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter Birthdate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_empType"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_empQuery"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3"
                android:minLines="3"
                android:maxLines="8"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="Enter Query"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"/>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_empcontact"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="Enter Contact Number"
                android:padding="5dp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_empemailid"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="Enter Email Id"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn__emp_postQuery"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="SUBMIT"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_corpempquery_emp_resetQuery"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="RESET"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Tab_1.java

```
public class Tab_1 extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    public Tab_1()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Tab_2.java and tab_2.xml are quite same as that of Tab_1 and tab_1 respectively.

Please help. Thank you.